# preg_match for regex expression

Tags: preg-match, eregi

Please help me to convert this code to preg_match

```
$blacklist = $db->query("SELECT `content` FROM `" . TABLE_PREFIX . "blacklist` WHERE `type`='$type'");
while ($blacklisted = $db->fetch_array($blacklist))
{
    if (is_array($input))
    {
        foreach ($input as $entry)
        {
            if (eregi($blacklisted['content'], $entry))
                print_error($msg);
        }
    }
    else if (eregi($blacklisted['content'], $input))
    {
        print_error($msg);
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I convert ereg expressions to preg in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6270004/how-can-i-convert-ereg-expressions-to-preg-in-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`eregi` used to be used like that to see if one string is in another. It was not the proper use. You can do the same with `stripos`

```
$blacklist = $db->query("SELECT `content` FROM `" . TABLE_PREFIX . "blacklist` WHERE `type`='$type'");
while ($blacklisted = $db->fetch_array($blacklist))
{
    if (is_array($input))
    {
        foreach ($input as $entry)
        {
            if (false !== stripos($entry, $blacklisted['content']))
                print_error($msg);
        }
    }
    else if (false !== stripos($input, $blacklisted['content']))
    {
        print_error($msg);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the eregi section using preg_match or strpos

Comment: I just added one. This is only assuming that `$backlisted['content']` is not actually a regular expression. Can you verify this?

Comment: Its not a regular expression but when a form is submitted it retrieves certain keywords and blocks it if it matches. This feature is now not working. So should you use preg_match for it ?

Comment: No, as I just said, you should use `stripos`